# How to limit what is logged in syslog

Tags: 7, log-messages

I changed error logging so that errors are being written to `/var/log/drupal.log`, switching from using Drupal's `dlog` to `syslog`, following [these instructions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/syslog/overview), in order to reduce resources used to write them to the Drupal database. All is well with that but when I tail the log file, it's reporting all the page not founds, login attempts and other annoying information that I don't want. How can I configure the `.log` so that it is limiting what is being written to it, or so that it writes different types of messages to a different .log. For example, can I config the log to ignore "page not found" warnings, but put "access denied" and "php" warnings in different respective logs?

Debian uses `rsyslog` and I needed to enable `syslog` module in the CMS and edit the `.conf` (in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`) to include a line that was needed for the CMS to interact with it.

Now, if I had more than one domain, I could use the following code to separate logs for each domain. Can I use something similar to separate types of messages instead?

```
if $programname == 'drupal_www_example_com' then /var/log/drupal/drupal_www_example_com.log
& ~

local0.* /var/log/drupal/others.log
& ~
```

How do I find out the name of the string I should use instead of `$programname`? It's probably `$type`. I'm thinking something like this would be added to the rsyslog.conf:

```
if $[type_of_message] == 'name_of_type_of_message' then /var/log/drupal/drupal_access_denied.log
& ~

local0.* /var/log/drupal/drupal.log
& ~
```

Also, the problem with the above idea is that it chooses one thing and logs the rest to `drupal.log`; I'm not sure on the syntax to create the "or if" statement to give it more instructions.

Note: `local0.*` is the syslog facility I defined in the CMS. I am not sure if this belongs in the Drupal community or if I should post to stackoverflow.

Edit: for now, I'm fine with running `tail /var/log/drupal.log | grep php` to filter messages by type "PHP", etc. I am a little concerned about how large the log is though.